# installing ubuntu on my windows 10 laptop

Tags: 16.04, tag

Installing ubuntu on my windows 10 laptop, do my files and programs stay, or do I need to reinstall all my programs

Comment: Are you installing it on a virtual machine or dual boot? In any case, all your files will stay, unless if you choose to dual boot, *you* explicilty choose to remove Windows and install Ubuntu alone.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to create a dual boot system with win 10 and ubuntu are:
 Steps For Dual Booting Windows 10 And Ubuntu
The steps required for dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu are as follows:

```
Backup your Windows 10 operating system (optional but highly recommended)
Create a Ubuntu USB drive
Enable booting from a USB drive
Shrink the Windows 10 partition to make space for Ubuntu
Boot into Ubuntu live environment and install Ubuntu
Amend the boot order to make sure Ubuntu can boot
```

[source](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html)